# Отправка формы ajax после авторизации Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

На сайте стандартными средствами проходит авторизация.

Если на странице вывести `<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>`
, то выведет авторизованного пользователя (id)

Но если через AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                data : $formInfo.serialize(),
                cache: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
```

То с сервера возвращает 0, т.е. не авторизован.
Попробовал включить отправку куков, `withCredentials: true`, но так и не сработало.
Как правильно отправить AJAX запрос от авторизованного клиента.

На сервере создал свой плагин для принятия AJAX запросов.
Уже работает и авторизация, и регистрация.

```
register_rest_route('wc/v2', 'users/set-info', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'pl_user_endpoint_set_info',
));


function pl_user_endpoint_set_info($request = null) {
$response = array();
$parameters = $request->get_body_params();

$response['response'] = $parameters;
$response['message'] = get_current_user_id();
$response['cookie'] = $_COOKIE;//проверка, пришли ли куки

return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);
```

}

Плагин зарегистрирован на action rest_api_init

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'pl_wp_rest_endpoints');
```

Код отправляется на клиенте с формы, но пока не обрабатывал параметры, мне бы сначала узнать, как это сделать, чтобы сервер понял, что клиент авторизован.

Ответ сервера:
[image: Ответ сервера]

Comment: Что за ajax, в какой момент отправляется, какой код ему отвечает на сервере, где этот код, по какому url: url, - сплошные загадки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, [Kudryavtsev Maxim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224585/kudryavtsev-maxim), натолкнул на нужно направление. Да, если сделать запрос AJAX, то `var_dump(wp_get_current_user())` возвращает пустой массив. Т.е. нет пользователей. Оказывается, просто wordpress считает такой запрос непроверенным, поэтому требует дополнительной аутентификации.
Нашёл решение здесь [Authentication rest ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/). Надо просто передавать в скрипт `nonce`

В function.php после подключения скрипта:

```
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'wpApiSettings', array(
        'root' => esc_url_raw(rest_url()),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
    ));
```

Сам AJAX запрос:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: 'POST',
   processData: false,
   data : $formInfo.serialize(),
   beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
   },
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Хук `rest_api_init` выполняется до получения информации о состоянии твоего пользователя. Добавь в код своего обработчика следующеe
`var_dump(wp_get_current_user())`. Если увидишь `null` либо пустой объект - мое предложение верно.

Решение здесь только одно - замена хука. Точно знаю что данные о пользователе доступны на хуке `template_redirect`, однако, с REST API Wordpress'а у меня опыта нет никакого.